# How I can lock a package to a minor version in Fedora 33?

Tags: linux, fedora, packages, dnf

I have a VM running Fedora 33 but recently I find out the VM crashing because the kernel was updated to the latest version (see `dnf info kernel` below). I have also found that kernel 5.8.x makes the VM work properly. My current kernel version is as follow:

```
❯ uname -r
5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64
```

I have found several blog post about this topic that uses the `versionlock` plugin from DNF but what they do not explain - not sure if because it is not possible - is how to lock a package to a minor version. I would like to continue receiving updates for 5.8.x but not update to 5.9.x because of what I have said above. Locking the kernel to `kernel-5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64` will make me stop receiving updates for the minor. Using `kernel-5.8.*` did not work for me. After performing a `dnf update` I saw the kernel coming as `5.9.8`.

Can I get some help locking the kernel (or any package) to a minor version?

Here is the current kernel version which is known will break my VM:

```
❯ dnf info kernel
...   
Available Packages
Name         : kernel
Version      : 5.9.8
Release      : 200.fc33
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 7.5 k
Source       : kernel-5.9.8-200.fc33.src.rpm
Repository   : updates
Summary      : The Linux kernel
URL          : https://www.kernel.org/
License      : GPLv2 and Redistributable, no modification permitted
Description  : The kernel meta package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be any more 5.8 updates once 5.9 has started shipping (there may be more 5.8.x releases of the kernel, but they won't be released as Fedora updates) so you might as well lock to the version you have already.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that for now until the issue gets fixed for newer kernel!